# How to create mysql database backup file of every day to day update?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine, I am building a web application of a Bank. Therefore I need to backup the database at least once a day and to backup the whole database everyday does not sound efficient. So I want to know how to create the backup file of the database only holding the transactions of current day.

Comment: @Starx: yes, so, serverfault. And you're looking for replication probably, with daily dumps on the replicating slave.

Answer (score 1):

Make Incremental Backups by Enabling the Binary Log.

> MySQL supports incremental backups:
>   You must start the server with the
>   --log-bin option to enable binary logging; see Section 5.2.4, “The
>   Binary Log”. The binary log files
>   provide you with the information you
>   need to replicate changes to the
>   database that are made subsequent to
>   the point at which you performed a
>   backup. At the moment you want to make
>   an incremental backup (containing all
>   changes that happened since the last
>   full or incremental backup), you
>   should rotate the binary log by using
>   FLUSH LOGS.

More on:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

Answer (score 1):

Try MySQL binary logging.  Back up the day's binlogs only.